# How can i register when text and shapes has been clicked on?

Tags: processing

```java
rect(x, y, 100, 100)
text("click here", 50, 50)
```

Is there a way to use `mousePressed()` so it registers when these two items have been clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for **collision detection**. Specifically, you're probably looking for **point-rectangle collision detection**, to determine whether the mouse is inside a rectangle.

Google is your friend, but here's an example:

```java
float rectX;
float rectY;
float rectWidth;
float rectHeight;

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  rectX = 50;
  rectY = 100;
  rectWidth = 200;
  rectHeight = 100;
}

void draw() {
  background(64);

  if (mouseX > rectX && mouseX < rectX + rectWidth && mouseY > rectY && mouseY < rectY + rectHeight) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  } 
  else {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
  }

  rect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection in Processing.